# Match Arabic word with regex that ends with “#”?

Tags: regex

I use this for matching if there its '#' in beginning of word

```
/(?!\b)(#\S+\b)/
```

it takes everything after '#'.

But now I need to find all Arabic word who ends with "#" or for start how can I find all word end with "#"?

I try `\b[A-Za-z]*#\b` but dont work :(

Comment: [A-Za-z] won't match any Arabic letters.

Comment: What is the language?

Comment: @nhahtdh Er... Arabic...

Comment: @Bojangles: I am asking for the programming language that he is using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[A-Za-z]` would match ASCII alphabets..You need to specify arabic unicode range to match arabic words

You can try this

```
\b[\u0600—\u06FF]+#(?=\s|$)
```

[This](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0600.pdf) is a pretty good reference for Arabic unicode range..

---

`[\u0600—\u06FF]` covers the complete arabic unicode range which includes digits,numeric symbols...

If you want to match arabic alphabets only use this range

```
[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FF]
```

Comment: Thanks man... But still I have problem... When I write Arabic for my mind '#' is on the end of word but actually for algorithm hi is in the beginning of word. Because 'Right To Left' writhing rules... Mu old function wont work /(?!\b)(#\S+\b)/

Comment: I need to identify for example 'وةىةى#' from 'بسشبسش بسش بسش #وةىةى وةىسش' Its tricky even to write :(

Comment: For now I use simply '#+\S+/' . Its hard to identify white space when typing from right to left. I make hash tag and I need to identify if someone type Arabic also

Answer (score 1):

To match arabic word you should use only arabic alphabets.

```
\u0621-\u063A\u0641-\u064A\u0660-\u0669\s
```

Your regex would be:

```
\b[\u0621-\u063A\u0641-\u064A\u0660-\u0669\s]*#\b
```