# Find arabic words using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, arabic, summernote, non-english

I using this pattern to find any word in the string:
\b(\w{1,})

but this can't find arabic words. How can I change this pattern to find both english and arabic words?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide exemple of matches you want on arabic sentence? I don't know about spaces in arabic but if you need to only delimit words maybe you can use a regular `.split(' ')`?

Comment: Arabic spaces are as same as english spaces. But I should use regex instead of .split(' ').. @antoni

Comment: {1,} can be replaced by +.

Answer (score 2):

Regex \w is an alias for A-z, 0-9, and _ (underscore) and will not match arabic unicode range. To include characters other than A-z you need to specify them, for example

```
[A-z\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FF]+
```

For explanation about character codes see  [Match Arabic word with regex that ends with “#”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612882/match-arabic-word-with-regex-that-ends-with)

Comment: I need just arabic words without # in end. Words are seperated by space. I am unfamiliar with regular expressions and I can't remove # mark from end! @smirnov

Comment: I don't know how I can do it! @smirnov

Comment: if you don't know - tell "I don't know", but not "I can't". The above link gives an overview what needs to be done and # is just a particular case which can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If your text only includes English and Arabic, and you want to sort the results, you could use this:

`([^x00-\x7F ]+)` for the Arabic text and this: `(\w+)` for the English text

The first part captures all characters other than the English set plus a space; the second part captures English characters (plus _).

Answer (score 0):

Like smirnov said, that regex you're using will only find Latin strings. For Arabic you should use `[\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufbc1]|[\ufbd3-\ufd‌​3f]|[\ufd50-\ufd8f]|‌​[\ufd92-\ufdc7]|[\uf‌​e70-\ufefc]|[\uFDF0-‌​\uFDFD]` (which should find all Arabic characters, even weird ones like ؁.)

Depending on what you're trying to do, you might want to split the string into a list and process it that way (that's what I usually end up doing when I'm dealing with mixed-language texts). Then you can identify the language of each word and process it accordingly.